# BuddyPress: Limit user activity posts by role, code always defaults to $max_posts = 0?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have written a function to limit user activity updates by user role and limited to a certain number per day. The problem I have is that in the switch statement all the cases/blocks get skipped and goes straight to default and ignores all the wp roles.

The default doesn't allow any posts and gives the error message.

Thanks for any input you can provide.

You can view the code [here](https://github.com/AiresDagraca/BP_activity_restrictions/blob/main/bp_activity_restrictions.php)

```
<?php

// Limit activity posts by day and user role
function limit_activity_posts($user_id)
{
    // get the current user role
    $user_role = get_userdata($user_id)->roles[0];

    // set the maximum number of posts based on user role
    switch ($user_role) {
        case "subscriber":
            $max_posts = 3;
            break;
        case "contributor":
            $max_posts = 5;
            break;
        case "editor":
            $max_posts = 10;
            break;
        case "administrator":
            $max_posts = -1;
            break;
        default:
            $max_posts = 0;
    }

    // check the number of posts for the current user
    $today = strtotime("today midnight");
    $args = [
        "user_id" => $user_id,
        "date_query" => [
            [
                "after" => $today,
                "inclusive" => true,
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $count = bp_activity_get($args, "total");

    // if the maximum number of posts is reached, prevent new post submission
    if ($max_posts >= 0 && $count >= $max_posts) {
        bp_core_add_message(
            sprintf(
                __(
                    "You have reached the maximum number of posts allowed for today (%d).",
                    "buddypress"
                ),
                $max_posts
            ),
            "error"
        );
        bp_core_redirect(bp_get_activity_directory_permalink());
    }
}
add_action("bp_activity_before_save", "limit_activity_posts");
```

The result I was expecting was to have each wp role to have their own daily limit.

This version is the simple from what I originally had,  it was in the form of a plugin with options for the admin. Ran into multiple issues so I settled with just going for a function using wp codebox for safety.

Comment: The hook passes an _array_, not a variable.  So, using your syntax, the user id would probably be `$user_id['user_id']`.  Some simple debugging would point out your error.